Evaluate Bezier Curve like cubic-bezier in css
My problem is simple I want to get the value at a specific t value of a Bezier curve that has 2 points. One at position (0, 0) and the other at position (1, 1). Both have one tangent with both an x and y coordinate. Weirdly, when I scoured the internet I ended up with both the x and y coordinate at the t value. Is it possibly to make a method that takes both tangents x and y coordinates as well as t as parameters and return the evaluated value like it is with the cubic-bezier transition effect.
My core problem in understanding resources about bezier curves is that the output axis y does not take x coordinates of tangents and positions into account which makes no sense to me.
I don't care about the programming language although Javascript would be preferred. Mathematical formulas would be OK too. Thanks in advance :).
